# pseudocode function to return two results for processing a tree

Tags: algorithm, function, tree, procedure, pseudocode

I'm trying to write a pseudocode for a recursive function that should process a binary tree. But the problem is that the function should return two variables. I know that functions are supposed to return on variable, and for more return values they should use `list`, `array` or `vector`, but I don't know how to present it as a pseudocode.

Does it look correct for a pseudocode?

```
function get_min(node *p)
begin
     if (p==NULL) then        
          return list(0,0);
     else 
          (vl,wl) = get_min(p->left)
          (vr,wr) = get_min(p->right)
          if (vl > vr) then
              return list(vr + p->cost, 1)
          else
              return list(vl + p->cost, 0)
          end if
     end if
end function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it's pseudo-code, just about anything goes.

However, I'd rather go for omitting `"list"`:

```
return (0, 0)
return (vr + p->cost, 1)
return (vl + p->cost, 0)
```

There doesn't seem to be any real benefit to putting `"list"` there - the `(..., ...)` format pretty clearly indicates returning two values already - there's no need to explicitly say you're returning them in a `list`.

Side note: You mention `list`, `array` or `vector`, but `pair` is another option in some languages, or wrapping the two in an object (typically giving the advantage of compile-time type checking - not really applicable in pseudo-code, obviously).

You could consider replacing `"list"` with `"pair"` instead of removing it if you wish to make it clear that the function only ever returns exactly 2 values.

Comment: I just want to make sure that nobody would complain that `function` returns just one variable.

Comment: When they say language agnostic, do they mean OO languages or include functional programming languages and anything else which I have little to no clue about?

Comment: @mLstudent33 What pseudocode looks like can vary wildly, be anything really and doesn't have to be understandable by any given person. Although, in order to maximise the number of people who can understand it, I would advise others against using functionality or syntax that would only make sense to someone familiar with a specific language (unless your intended audience consists exclusively of people who understand that language).

Answer (score 0):

If you pass parameters as reference , then there is no need to use `lists` as @Dukeling suggested .

```
void function get_min(node *p , int *cost , int * a)
begin
     if (p==NULL) then        
          *cost =0 ; *a =0 ; return ;
     else 
           get_min(p->left ,vl ,vw)
           get_min(p->right , vr , wr)
          if (vl > vr) then
              *cost = vl + p->cost , *a =0 ; return;  
              else
              *cost = vl + p->cost , *a =0 ; return ;
          end if
     end if
end function
```